# NIST randomness test suite returns igamc:UNDERFLOW for most of the tests

Tags: random

I have a random sequence of size of 1 million and in order to use the [NIST test suite](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Random-Bit-Generation/Documentation-and-Software/Guide-to-the-Statistical-Tests), I have converted the sequence, which is stored in Windows txt format, into BCD and obviously, the length of file becomes 4 million. So I run the test and set the bitstreams to 1 and select "[0] ASCII - A sequence of ASCII 0's and 1's". But the program shows numerous "igamc: UNDERFLOW" errors. Could anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: What language are you using? Also, you should post your code - it's difficult to find an error otherwise.

Comment: @VladimirShevyakov, I am using NIST Test suite. In fact, I have generated this sequence using other tool and now, I want to check its quality using the mentioned tool. https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Random-Bit-Generation/Documentation-and-Software/Guide-to-the-Statistical-Tests

Comment: You can look also [Dieharder: A Random Number Test Suite](http://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to convert the file beforehand. 
The txt format works just fine.

You can select "[0] ASCII - A sequence of ASCII 0's and 1's", if the random sequence is stored in binary in the txt file e.g., "01101110".

Otherwise, you should convert the sequence beforehand (e.g., if the sequence is stored in (hexa)decimals)